# Are the parameter values automatically cleared after executing a batch of SQL commands with a Java PreparedStatemen?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have the following code snippet:

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    preparedStatement.setObject(1, someValue);
    preparedStatement.addBatch();
    if ((i + 1) % 100 == 0) {
        preparedStatement.executeBatch();
    }
}
```

so I want to execute one command around 100 000 times with different values. My question is: are the parameters from the PreparedStatement cleared after each call to executeBatch() or do I have to explicitly call preparedStatement.clearParameters() after calling executeBatch() in order to make sure that there will be executed only the last 100 commands?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I can see here: http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/sun/jdbc/odbc/JdbcOdbcStatement.java.html

`executeBatch()` calls `clearBatch()` in the end.

But there is no guarantee for that will be exactly the same in other implementations.

Comment: *"But there is no guarantee for that will be exactly the same in other implementations."* Right, so this isn't really useful.

Answer (score 16):

YES. According to section 15.1.2 of [JDBC 3.0](http://java.cnam.fr/iagl/biblio/spec/jdbc-3_0-fr-spec.pdf) and section 14.1.2 of [JDBC 4.1](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jdbc-4_1-mrel-spec/jdbc4.1-fr-spec.pdf):

> Calling the method executeBatch closes the calling Statement object’s
>   current result set if one is open. **The statement’s batch is reset to
>   empty once executeBatch returns**.

It's unfortunate that such an important detail ended up almost as a fine print.

In addition to the example already mentioned, the jtds driver also does a clearBatch() in the finally block of [executeBatch()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sourceforge.jtds/jtds/1.3.1/net/sourceforge/jtds/jdbc/JtdsStatement.java#JtdsStatement.executeBatch%28%29).

Answer (score 9):

I'd say the more relevant question was whether the *batch* is cleared. Although it seems like a reasonable assumption, barring the documentation *explicitly saying* that it's cleared (and I don't see anything on [`executeBatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch%28%29) saying that), I'd use [`clearBatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch%28%29) explicitly on the theory that if an implementation *does* clear the batch, `clearBatch` will be a quick no-op; and if it doesn't, well, then I needed to do it.

**Update**: While the `executeBatch` documentation doesn't say so, see [Bogdan Calmac's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22005160/157247): Apparently the JDBC documentation **does** say successful completion clears the batch.

Comment: What do you think about the spec fragment I posted below? Do you think that's binding enough (or clear enough) for a driver developer?

Comment: @BogdanCalmac I'd say that one should check its choosen JDBC driver behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I would rather say, that it is better to clear it explicitly. Some JDBC drivers don't clear internal buffers after `executeBatch()`.
An explicit call to `clearBatch()` is necessary to avoid errors like `IndexOutOfBoundException` as some logical errors may also be introduced.

Thanks!